# Validation error while adding new item to MongoDB array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My requirement is to look for an email id in a collection and if it exists, need to add new enquiry details for that user.If user does not exists,then a new document with email id and all other details of user should be created in the collection.

I am able to successfully create user and corresponding details.But when i am trying to add a new item in 'enquiry' array by filtering the collection using email id,its giving a validation error ''validation failed: emailID: Path `emailID` is required.'

I am not sure why MongoDb is throwing this error.I don't want to update email id.I just want to  add a new item under 'enquiry' array

Model is-

```
var userEenquirySchema = new Schema({

        emailID: {
            type: String,
             required: true, unique: true, trim: true, match: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/           
        },

        enquiry: [{

            userFullName: { type: String, required: true, unique: false, trim: true},

           isdCode: {
                type: Number, required: true,
                min: [1, 'The value of path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) is beneath the limit ({MIN}).'],
                max: [200, 'The value of path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) exceeds the limit ({MAX}).']
            },

            primaryPhonenumber: {
                type: Number,
                validate: {
                    validator: function (primaryPhonenumber) {
                        if (isNaN(primaryPhonenumber) || primaryPhonenumber.toString().trim().length != 10) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    message: '{VALUE} is not a valid primary phone number!'
                },
                required: [true, 'User phone number required']
            },

            procedureName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },

            commuMedium: { type: String, required: false, unique: false, trim: true, default: 'English' },

            caseDescription: { type: String, required: true, unique: false, trim: true },

            attachmentFlag: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N'], default: 'N' },

            attachmentName: { type: String, required: false}, 

            response: [{
                mediNovitaResponse: { type: String, required: false, unique: false, trim: true },
                respondedBy: { type: String, required: false, unique: false, trim: true },
                contactedMethod: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Phone', 'Email', 'Both']},
                emailResponseSent: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N'] },
                nextFollowUpDate: { type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now },
                followUpAssignee: { type: String, required: false, unique: false, trim: true },
                followUpNote: { type: String, required: false, unique: false, trim: true },
                respondedAt: { type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now },
            }],

            updated_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
        }]
});
```

Controller code to add new item to  enquiry array -

```
userEnquiryModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "emailID": req.body['emailID'] }, {"$push": {
                    enquiry : [{
                        userFullName: req.body['userFullName'],
                        isdCode: parseInt(req.body["isdCode"]),
                        primaryPhonenumber: parseInt(req.body["primaryPhonenumber"]),
                        procedureName: req.body["procedureName"],
                        commuMedium: req.body["commuMedium"],
                        caseDescription: req.body["caseDescription"],
                        attachmentFlag: req.body["attachment"],
                        attachmentName: req.body["attachmentName"],
                        response: []
                    }]
              }
            }
```

Comment: you have somewhere used the wrong variable while inserting your email into your db

Comment: that will even work if you put emailId required to false:

Comment: ```emailID: {
            type: String,
             required: false, unique: true, trim: true, match: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/           
        },```

Comment: or you are updating their fields and using the same schema in which email id is set required: true so that can also create problem, I think its required

Comment: emailID is the primary key and i would like to set it as required: true.Same code with an if condition is used for insertion of new document and adding new doc to existing collection.Insertion of new doc works just fine,but adding to existing array is throwing error